# You custom database IdentityDbContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication

I was trying to develop an application and created my own database which then was reflected to an entity model using database first. So I now already have let's say myOwnDBContext. 
Then I thaught it wuld be a nice idea to mix it with the classes generated by IdentityDbContext. But when i just changed the connection string in IdentityModel like this

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("myOwnDBConnectionString")
        {
        }
    }
```

The tables were not generated as I would expect in myOwnDB but instead I received the following error.

> The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the
>   current context.

Is there a way I can mix the defualt database of IdentityDbContext with my own databse?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this can work without using EF migrations, but I do have it working with migrations. Specifically, two DbContext derived classes (one for custom entities, one derived from IdentityDbContext).

For the migrations I had to enable-migrations from the package manager console for both contexts and use the -MigrationsDirectory parameter to place the two sets of migrations into distinct folders (a new feature for EF6).

Then when running update-database the tables are created properly for each context. The update-database command will need a -ConfigurationTypeName parameter to specify the exact migration to use.